# Mesh comes off when moving bones

Tags: bones, bone.constraints

I am a beginner of rigging bones and have a problem I've been working on for 2days now.I am currently trying make an animation that moves as though a tranparent person is hanging it on his body. So first I tried rigging the object and then applying rigid body using "rigid body gen" addon. The addon helped me wiggle the strings of the bag but when I try move the bag body(the bone I named "spineDown"), the strings(named bones "legRF" "legRB" "legLF" "legLB") comes off and will not follow the body.

I am assuming that there is a parenting problem..? Or is there a way to attach the meshes?
Here is the file. Could somebody help please?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/eivg9czy5xisa8o/bagwalking_20230620.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1) Inspection

If you look in the outliner, you can see that your "leg" bones are not parented to spineDown:

[image]

But constraint icon shows up on them. And if we look which constraints are these, we can see some of them constrained as Child Of other leg bones, and those bones themselves constrained Child Of "rbg...." mesh objects.

Since they are the one driving the movement of the bones, I guess they are the ones carrying the Rigid Body simulation. A quick look in the Properties Editor > Physics Properties with one of the mesh objects selected confirms that:

[image]

Empties also have these. Plus the relationship dashed lines in the viewport indicate they are somehow children of the "spineDown.001" mesh object. Which is also confirmed by their physics properties:

[image]

Noting, "spineDown.001" is constrained Child Of your armature object.

### 2) Diagnosis

I guess all the objects you have inside the "bag" collection were generated by the "rigid body gen" addon. But there are a couple issues:

1. They are parented to your armature object, not to your "spineDown" bone.
2. "spineDown.001" is constrained Child Of your armature.

### 3) Solution

1. in the outliner, select the first object in the bag collection, then hold shift and click the last object of that collection to select all the objects in between.
2. In the viewport, hold <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and select the armature. Release <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>. Switch to Pose Mode, and select the spineDown bone.
3. With your mouse in the viewport: <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > Set Parent To Bone Relative (should be the last option)
4. Since "spineDown.001" is now parented to the "spineDown" bone, the constraint is redundant. Select "spineDown.001" in the bag collection, and delete the constraints in Properties editor > Constraints tab.

### 4) Result

[image: demo gif]